# How can I prevent a "rogue" front end?

Tags: api

I developed my product, which is exposed via API+web+mobile app.

How can I prevent a 3rd party from developing its own front end and plug it on my backend?

I'm not talking about a simple phishing attack but a "chaotic-good" guy, that thinks my frontend sucks and wishes to provide my service on his terms and get away with my ads revenue, got it?

Details:

1. The Api is exposed by Azure API Management service.
2. Backend is .Net 5

Comment: I'm not sure this is a security question, then,

Comment: I think that it is, because it's the same exploit a phishing would use... the guy could log everything since it would all be exposed by his front... which is more troublesome than a phishing

Comment: No, a phisher would create a fake login page and just always return an error, rather than worry about trying to forward users to your real login backend.

Comment: think of it this way: what would prevent me from creating a mobile based search app, relaying all queries to google?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica so naive... if the phisher does this he will raise suspicion rather fast... the end user will soon contact the real app owners and they would become aware of it and shut it down... this guy you described, is a minor-league guy... the major-league guy will, for example, redirect you to the real login page after you entered your password and have you believe that a system error occur and you should login again

Comment: But what you said doesn't require them to use your API directly either.

Comment: the most successful phisher is the one who re-implements your front end... this way the end user is actually attacked 24x7 and will never be aware of that... "what are you saying dude? www.my.bank is not the site for myBank? yes it is man, I used it everyday! I even contracted a loan on it and cashed it on that ATM... I even authorized my mobile phone on it"... see?

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic solution. Only if you **authenticate** the users of your API, you can be sure nobody else is using it. Any other approaches like prohibiting access based on IPs or using any HTTP headers with special content can easily be circumvented.

Comment: given that the user enter their user/apss on the "chaotic-good" guy, wouldn't he be able to authenticate them?

Comment: @Leonardo: If users choose strong passwords and don't disclose them, then no, nobody else except legitimate users will be able to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping someone else to make a new front-end for your application. All one needs to know to make a new front-end is your API. If you have a  publicly documented API, anyone can see how to interact with your application without a dedicated front-end using something like `curl` to make HTTP requests. Even if you don't have your documentation publicly open, users can just look at the requests made by your front-end by using their browser's dev tools or a proxy like Burp Suite to see what kind of requests are made and possibly figure out how to make legitimate requests later. Once we know how to make requests to your server, we can make our own front-end.